# install mongodb-10gen failed with apt-get

Tags: mongodb

Install mongodb-10gen as http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-debian/ but got error below:

```
dpkg: error processing /var/cache/apt/archives/mongodb-10gen_2.2.0_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 trying to overwrite '/usr/bin/mongoimport', which is also in package mongodb-clients 1:1.4.4-3
configured to not write apport reports
                                      dpkg-deb: subprocess paste killed by signal (Broken pipe)
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/mongodb-10gen_2.2.0_amd64.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Answer (score 60, accepted):

A bug here https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-6910

apt-get remove mongodb-clients first, and then the installation of mongodb-10gen should work.