# Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)

Tags: mongodb, installation

Reading package lists... Done

Building dependency tree

Reading state information... Done

```
The following package was automatically installed and is no longer required:
      cordova-ubuntu-2.8-examples
Use 'apt-get autoremove' to remove it.
    The following NEW packages will be installed:
      mongodb-10gen
    0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
    Need to get 0 B/87.1 MB of archives.
    After this operation, 221 MB of additional disk space will be used.
    (Reading database ... 250020 files and directories currently installed.)
    Unpacking mongodb-10gen (from .../mongodb-10gen_2.4.8_i386.deb) ...
    Obsolete conffile /etc/init.d/mongodb has been modified by you, renaming to .dpkg-bak
    dpkg: error processing /var/cache/apt/archives/mongodb-10gen_2.4.8_i386.deb (--unpack):
     trying to overwrite '/usr/bin/mongos', which is also in package mongodb-10gen-unstable-mongos 2.5.2
    dpkg-deb: error: subprocess paste was killed by signal (Broken pipe)
    Errors were encountered while processing:
     /var/cache/apt/archives/mongodb-10gen_2.4.8_i386.deb
    E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

please see here! worked for me:
[install mongodb-10gen failed with apt-get](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12480935/install-mongodb-10gen-failed-with-apt-get)

A bug here https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-6910

apt-get remove mongodb-clients

and then the installation of mongodb-10gen should work.