# apt-get install mongodb-10gen failed

Tags: linux, mongodb, debian

I want to install mongoDB on Debian. The problem is when I try to do that the output is like this:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
mongodb-10gen is already the newest version.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 4 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue [Y/n]? y
Setting up mongodb-10gen (2.4.10) ...
invoke-rc.d: unknown initscript, /etc/init.d/mongodb not found.
dpkg: error processing mongodb-10gen (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 100
Errors were encountered while processing:
 mongodb-10gen
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

I've searched about that and found some solutions like:
[install mongodb-10gen failed with apt-get](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12480935/install-mongodb-10gen-failed-with-apt-get/12480936#12480936)
But when try to run this command:

```
apt-get remove mongodb-clients
```

The result is:

```
[root@Takhalof-srv ~]$ apt-get remove mongodb-clients
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Package 'mongodb-clients' is not installed, so not removed
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 4 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Setting up mongodb-10gen (2.4.10) ...
invoke-rc.d: unknown initscript, /etc/init.d/mongodb not found.
dpkg: error processing mongodb-10gen (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 100
Errors were encountered while processing:
 mongodb-10gen
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

When I try to run this command:

```
sudo service mongodb restart
```

The result is:

```
mongodb: unrecognized service
```

When I use apt-get -f install the result is:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 4 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Setting up mongodb-10gen (2.4.10) ...
invoke-rc.d: unknown initscript, /etc/init.d/mongodb not found.
dpkg: error processing mongodb-10gen (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 100
Errors were encountered while processing:
 mongodb-10gen
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

I really confused and don't know what's the problem. What should I do?

Answer (score 0):

The error in your first command strongly suggest that the MongoDB server(/daemon) isn't installed. Try installing `mongodb-server`, then doing `apt-get -f install` to finish configuring any half installed packages.